# How to solve dependencies error when opening Spyder?

Tags: python, dependencies, spyder

I saw many similar posts recently but haven't seen a recent solution for this. I tried older solutions such as pip uninstall *jedi *and reinstalling, but that was not helpful. [The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtXko.png) says *nbconvert* so I thought I could give it a try and do pip install *nbconvert*, but I got 'already satisfied' messages. Tried restarting everything after uninstalling and reinstalling all the mentioned packages and didn't help. I got the same pop-up again. Spyder is working at the moment, but would be great to not get this pop-up every time I start.

Python 3.11
conda 23.11.0

Tried older solutions in stackoverflow and restarting everything but didn't help. Looks like a reoccurring problem and no recent solution.

Comment: Please do not post text, in your case error message as image, use formatted text instead. This will also help your question to be search-and-findable.

Comment: Tried this:: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8941

Still didn't help. I have only one environment and nbconvert seems like installed in my environment. I think I will try to create a new environment and start again.